# EJBCA CA Renewal

Tags: pki, ejbca

I am looking at a clear answer on to how to renew the CA successfully in EJBCA. We have thousands of client certificates already issued by the EJBCA which is actually working as a subCA signed by an external CA. The process is indeed documented here https://www.ejbca.org/docs/Renewing_a_SubCA_Signed_by_an_External_CA.html but it does not state clearly, what will happen to the already issued client certificates. Will they continue to be successfully validated via the new CA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That link give two options for renewing the key:

#### 1. Using the same CA signing key

If you refer to RFC 3647, this is the correct definition of a [renewal](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3647#section-4.4.6).  In this case, the keys remain the same and the certificate Subject remains the same.  Effectively, the *new* certificate is the same as the *old* albeit with different dates.

Relying parties will trust this certificate in the same way as they trusted the original.

#### 2. Generating new CA signing keys

The correct term for this is a [re-key](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3647#section-4.4.7).  The key changes and the Subject stays the same.  The certificate is a different certificate as far as any relying parties are concerned.  This may mean more work for you.

You'll first need to ascertain what will happen to the original CA certificate.  Will it expire or be revoked, or will it still be valid?

If it's being retired, you'll need to replace all certificates issued by that original CA certificate as they will only verify through the original CA.

If not, and you're re-keying for other reasons, for example the original CA certificate's CRL has become too large to manage, then there is no need to rush into replacing all your subscriber certificates. The old CA certificate will still verify those certificates, while subscriber certificates issued by the new CA certificate will be verified by the new CA certificate.

Comment: Thanks. We were able to carry out renewal using both options you listed out. As in our case, the original CA certificate is still valid, so our end users are not expected to get a new certificates. Decision btw option 1 and 2 depends on the cyber hygiene/security policies. We tested both and both work well.